# AG Grid with Redux Toolkit Query?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Im trying to integrate AG Grid server side model with Redux Toolkit Query but problem is I have external parameters that changes, but did not find how to handle this.

I have pagination/filters/sorting on, I think I cant just override the datasource or I might lose them?

Heres an example

```
function MyGrid({ param1, param2 }: props): ReactElement {
    // param1/param2 are updated here
    const [triggerPostData] = usePostDataMutation();

    const createDatasource: () => IServerSideDatasource = useCallback(() => {
        return {
            getRows: (parameters): void => {
                // param1/param2 arent updated here
                triggerPostData({ param1, param2, rowsRequestData: parameters.request })
                    .unwrap()
                    .then((data) => {
                        parameters.success({
                            rowData: data.results,
                            rowCount: data.resultCount
                        });
                        return parameters;
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        parameters.fail();
                    });
            }
        };
    }, [param1, param2, triggerPostData]);

    const onGridReady = useCallback(
        (parameters: GridReadyEvent): void => {
            parameters.api.setServerSideDatasource(createDatasource());
        },
        [createDatasource]
    );

    const agGridProperties: AgGridReactProps = {
        columnDefs,
        rowModelType: 'serverSide',
        cacheBlockSize: paginationPageSize,
        onGridReady
    };

    return <AgGridReact {...agGridProperties} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, datasource is set only once (in the greadReady callback).
Then when `param1` and `param2` are changed it makes new `createDatasource` function which is never used by grid.
I would suggest setting datasource via AgGridReact property `serverSideDatasource`

```js
function MyGrid({ param1, param2 }: props): ReactElement {
  // param1/param2 are updated here
  const [triggerPostData] = usePostDataMutation();

  const serverSideDatasource: IServerSideDatasource = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      getRows: (parameters): void => {
        // param1/param2 arent updated here
        triggerPostData({ param1, param2, rowsRequestData: parameters.request })
        ...
      },
    };
  }, [param1, param2, triggerPostData]);

  const agGridProperties: AgGridReactProps = {
    columnDefs,
    rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    serverSideDatasource,
    cacheBlockSize: paginationPageSize,
  };

  return <AgGridReact {...agGridProperties} />;
}
```

UPD: As @phry pointed out, the server-side row model is designed around an imperative approach through the getRows method, so it would not be practical to use RTK Query with Server-side model.

Comment: thats it probably! Im off atm will try this tomorow

Comment: Im facing another problem now tho... when param1 or 2 changes, the whole datasource is recreated so Im losing sorts/filters/pagination and such :/

Comment: @sherkal , remove `param1, param2` from your `useMemo` dependencies. And path params via grid context `<AgGridReact ... context={{param1, param2}} />`

After that, you can get params in your getRows method `getRows: ({request, context}) => {const [param1, param2] = context; ...}`

Answer (score 5):

RTK Query author here.
Honestly, from personal experience with AG-Grid's DataSources: If you have no *need* to use a third-party tool like RTK Query, just use normal fetch straight out of the box.
AG-Grid has its own cache and wants a lot of control over which request is made when - and RTK Query kinda does the same job. Instead of having two tools fight over "who does what", just use one tool. You don't need both in this instance.

Comment: Interesting! We disabled cache on this endpoint tho

Comment: Just consider it - from my experience, it's a pain to get AG-Grid synchronized nicely with an external data source that has its own lifecycle.

Comment: If you have to (websockets or something), look at applyServersideRowData, Note the docs are currently wrong, you need to have suppressServersideInfiniteScroll=false. They'll update soon. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model-configuration/#providing-additional-data